# How can I not confirm the action from Google api every time?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a **Desktop App** for Google Drive that create and set perms that i need. This app should work only for one account with google drive.
My problem is that when I launch an action, I always have to confirm this action in explorer. Can I somehow automatically send my data and confirmation to the server? I read about the access token, but it seems to be suitable only for web applications. I am based on the documentation from the Google API site.
And in future this should work from console.

My code right now:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const { AuthClient } = require('google-auth-library');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials)
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

async function saveCredentails(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        access_type: 'offline',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secred: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentails(client);
    }
    return client;
}

async function createFolder(authClient) {

    const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});
    const fileMetadata = {
      name: 'testmeows',
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    };
    try {
      const file = await service.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        fields: 'id',
      });
      console.log('Folder Id:', file.data.id);
      const body = {"role": "writer", "type": "anyone"}
      const result = await service.permissions.create({
            resource: body,
            fileId: file.data.id,
            //fields: 'id',
        });
      const align = `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/${file.data.id}?usp=sharing`;
        console.log(align);
      
    } catch (err) {

      throw err;
    }
  }

//module.exports = test;ф


authorize().then(createFolder).catch(console.error);
```

Well, how to better get refresh token without user invention and opening explorer on Desktop App Google Api?

Comment: It's unlikely anyone can help you without seeing the relevant code that causes the confirmation.

Comment: I have the same functions as here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs?hl=en_US#set_up_the_sample 
and function `authorize()` is opening explorer to confirm action and log in google account

Comment: As you appear to possibly be new here, your question itself should contain the relevant code and should stand alone without external links.  You can use external links to supplement, but the relevant code should be contained in your question.  You can use the "Edit" link below your question to modify it.

Comment: Okay, will add it later, when come back home

Comment: @Servantr Not sure what ` I always have to confirm this action in explorer.` means in this context, but if it is the browser opening to generate tokens, have you checked if `loadSavedCredentialsIfExist()` returns anything and the JSON creds file was properly saved? Because `authorize()` should exit if it finds a valid creds file previously cached.